# pipreqs gives blank file

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pip, amazon-sagemaker, requirements.txt

I am using SageMaker studio notebook and want to create a `requirements.txt`.

I tried two options:

1. `!pip freeze > requirements.txt`

This gives me more than 300 rows of listed dependencies.

2. `!pipreqs lib/`
   This gives me a blank file.

From what I learned, `pipreqs` seems better to provide all necessary information but not as overwhelmed as `pip freeze`. However, I am getting a blank file; is anything I am doing here wrong? I am expecting I should at least see `openai` and `pandas` in the `requirements.txt`.

Also, this is what I am getting from `session_info.show()`:

```bash
azure               NA
boto3               1.34.33
botocore            1.34.33
openai              0.28.0
pandas              2.2.0
session_info        1.0.0
utils               NA
```

Comment: What files are in the lib/ folder? I see packages imported in a python file in a folder, for example, `test/` if I run `pipreqs test/`.